# How to Debug Security Permission inside Sandbox solution

Tags: c#, .net, securityexception

I have created new AppDomain for Sandbox solution with following permissions:

```
        EvidenceBase[] hostEvidence = { new Zone(SecurityZone.Trusted) };
        Evidence evidence = new Evidence(hostEvidence, null);
        PermissionSet permissions = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(evidence);
```

Third Party Plugin is loaded successfully how ever some calls return SecurityException and I cant figured out from StackTrace what resources are required that triggers this exception.

How can I get more details from SecurityException?

Code for creating child domain:

```
    AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MySandBox", null, adSetup, permissions, fullTrustAssembly);
        ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(
            newDomain, typeof(PluginSandbox).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName,
            typeof(PluginSandbox).FullName
            );
        newDomainInstance = (PluginSandbox)handle.Unwrap();
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox` instead roll your own customised permission set tailored for that particular plug-in.  Also, I'm not entirely sure but I think `Zone(SecurityZone.Trusted)` will lead to permissions usually set aside for _trusted websites_ and no say an app sourced from the local LAN or My Computer.   Otherwise CAS throwing an exception for code doing something it shouldn't whilst running in a particular AppDomain is not unheard of

Comment: Btw, I assume you have setup the child App Domain, are using `childDomain.appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`; using partially trusted code; GAC etc.   Otherwise its not a sandbox.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/november/how-to-safely-host-untrusted-add-ins-with-the-net-framework-2-0.  Any chance you can show a stack trace?

Comment: Hi @MickyD! I have already tryied customized permissions and got only worse results. I got it working by using SecurityZone.MyComputer but obviously this is not the way to go for production. I have updated post with code for creating child domain. I think the only way I can solve this is by getting security details, this way I can give proper permissions. Stack trace points to constructor in one of entities inside third part library.